# What activity to expect when fermenting a lager?

Tags: fermentation, lagering

I have a lager in primary fermentation, with the temp in the fridge around 10C. The fridge smells of fermentation and the bubbler is not level, but I have not seen a single bubble escape from the bubbler.

This is my first lager, so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if this low activity is normal for a cold fermentation.

The starter that I made seemed to be fairly active.

Will a lager ever cause the bubbler to "purr", or is a very slow bubbler activity normal?

Thank you.

(I have not opened the fermenter since brewday last weekend and I have not taken new hydrometer readings either. Will do so tonight.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have a leak in the lid of your fermenter. 
You should see some bubbles.

If your hydrometer read shows that the beer attenuated, just make sure the lid is well closed and follow your normal fermenting schedule.

Comment: I have taken a reading and I am on 1.020 from 1.038, so there is activity. I think you are correct on the leak. I created a hole for my thermometer and it may be that I did not seal that properly. Thank you.